# Probability question - inclusion/exclusion doesn't work. What else possible here?

Tags: probability, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

I have the following question:

> Four men went to a party and hung their coats in a closet. When they
>   left, each of them randomly and uniformly picked a coat. What is the
>   probability that no one got the coat they came with to the party?

I tried to solve it with inclusion/exclusion:

`A_i` - Man #`i` took **not** his coat.
I know the probabilty space is `4!`.
 Hence I tried to calculate: $$P=\frac{|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|}{4!}$$

The problem is in the  inclusion/exclusion formula.

I don't know how to calculate the cardinality of the intersections. i.e.:$$|A_2\cap A_3|$$ 
Because if `man #2` took a coat that doesn't belong to `man #3` then the cardinality is 3*2 (the `man #2` can take 3 coats and `man #2` can take 2).

But, there is also an option `man #2` took a coat that belongs to `man #3` so I dont know how really calculate the cardinalities. It gets more complicated when there are more than 2 sets in the intersection.

Maybe inclusion/exclusion isn't the right tool here?

Comment: Such a permutation is known as a [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: @lulu Cant it be solved with Inclusion/exclusion? I prefer not using Derangement because we are not supposed to know it.

Comment: Sure, that's one of the standard approaches.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929005/derivation-of-derangement-with-inclusion-exclusion)

Comment: Note:  for four people you could simply list all the permutations and count the ones you want.  The other methods come in handy for larger collections.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it from your link to Wikipedia. It has an example similiar to my problem. Thank you

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion is the right tool, but you need to work with the complementary events. So let $B_i$ be the event that man $i$ takes his own coat, then $\Pr(B_i)=1/4$ and $\Pr(B_i\cap B_j)=1/12$ (because if man $i$ chooses his own coat, there are three coats left for man $j$, one of which is his).

The probability you want is $1-\Pr(B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3\cup B_4)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use derangement.

$4!\left(1 - 1 + \frac 1{2!} - \frac 1{3!} + \frac 1{4!} \right)$

$= 24\left(1 - 1 + \frac 12 - \frac 16 + \frac 1{24} \right)$

$= 9$